# Import data from Google Spreadsheet cell to WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a cell text from a Google Spreadsheet and insert into a post on WordPress using this code, but I'm pretty bad on JavaScript that I don't even know how to get the text without the alert.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhp9yFq8eXagN03gn-mCN3_KPWRc2EIpswDFpHJLflFOG-XU2OMktqj03gxvUBZMAp8gYwWO5Q3MVJ/pub?gid=942917560&single=true&range=d3&output=csv").done(function(result){
            alert(result);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: In your Wordpress post, go to Text mode and add a div like `<div id='spreadsheet'></div>`. Now in your script, instead of `alert(result)`, you use `jQuery("#spreadsheet").text(result);` (wordpress usually comes with jQuery, you don't need to add it yourself. you need to replace `$` with `jQuery` though)

Comment: Perfect! It worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Wordpress post, go to Text mode and add a div

```
<div id='spreadsheet'></div>
```

Now in your script do this to set the contents:

```
jQuery.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhp9yFq8eXagN03gn-mCN3_KPWRc2EIpswDFpHJLflFOG-XU2OMktqj03gxvUBZMAp8gYwWO5Q3MVJ/pub?gid=942917560&single=true&range=d3&output=csv").done(function(result){
    jQuery("#spreadsheet").text(result);
})
```

WordPress usually comes with jQuery, you don't need to add it yourself. You need to replace `$` with `jQuery` though.
You can also do this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.ajax("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhp9yFq8eXagN03gn-mCN3_KPWRc2EIpswDFpHJLflFOG-XU2OMktqj03gxvUBZMAp8gYwWO5Q3MVJ/pub?gid=942917560&single=true&range=d3&output=csv").done(function(result) {
        $("#spreadsheet").text(result);
    })
});
```

This will a) only run the function after the document is loaded and b) allow you to keep using `$` in your code.